# Не обновляется ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пытаюсь разобраться с MVVM и написал небольшое приложение. До определённого момента всё было прекрасно, но потом мой мозг сломался :(
Итак есть ListBox

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan ="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ListResult}" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}"/>
```

Есть соответствующее поле в VM:

```
private string[] listResult = { "Итоговый список" };
    public string[] ListResult
    {
        get => listResult;
        set
        {
            listResult = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ListResult");
        }
    }
```

И есть несколько кнопок которые меняют содержимое  ListResult и всё прекрастно отображается.
Вот для примера:

```
public RelayCommand MainCommand => new RelayCommand(o =>
{

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Folder))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Выберете папку со списком");
        return;
    }

    ListResult = lg.createList(Lvl);

});

public RelayCommand Level => new RelayCommand(o =>
{

    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Folder))
    {
        ListResult = lg.createList(Lvl);
    }
});

public RelayCommand FullList => new RelayCommand(o =>
{
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Folder))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Выберете папку со списком");
        return;
    }
    ListResult = lg.fullList();                         // Тут всё в порядке
});
```

Но в одном месте всё ломается :(
вот код:

```
public RelayCommand Sorted => new RelayCommand(o =>
    {    
        ListResult = lg.sorted(ListResult);  
    });
```

Тут я сортирую список и список сортируется (проверено) но во View ничего не меняется :( 
Почему?

Экспериментируя я нашёл очень убогий костыль. Если переписать код вот так:

```
public RelayCommand Sorted => new RelayCommand(o =>
{    
    string[] sortedList = lg.sorted(ListResult);
    ListResult = new string[] { "Раз", "Два" };
    ListResult = sortedList;
});
```

То всё прекрасно отображается. Как это работает???? Помогите пожалуйста.

Для понимания происходящего некторые указанные тут методы:

```
public string[] createList(bool lvl)
    {
        this.lvl = lvl;
        List<string> darklist = new List<string>();
        numberOfTracks = 0;
        list = new List<string>();
        darklist.Add("========================================");
        darklist.AddRange(makeList(inDir));
        if (darklist.Count == 1) darklist.Add(" Список пуст");
        darklist.Add("========================================");
        string[] result = darklist.ToArray();
        return result;
    }

internal string[] fullList()
    {
        list = new List<string>();
        numberOfTracks = 0;
        list.Add("========================================");
        string[] dir = Directory.GetFiles(inDir, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        int numberOfTr = 0;
        foreach (string file in dir)
        {
            numberOfTr++;
            list.Add("| " + numberOfTr.ToString("D4") + " | " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
        }
        if (list.Count == 1) list.Add(" Список пуст");
        list.Add("========================================");
        string[] result = list.ToArray();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: string[] sortedList = lg.sorted(ListResult);
ListResult = sortedList;    Ссылка меняется? А View нет :(

Comment: покажи методы lg.createList() и lg.fullList(), и возможно у меня получится ответить

Comment: string[] sortedList = lg.sorted(ListResult); sortedList - хранит ссылку на отсортированный ListResult
 ListResult = sortedList; снова ссылка на ListResult

Comment: Методы добавил в конец сообщения, но кажеться я понял. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете Binding к массиву строку "ListResult", а не к его содержимому, т.е. привязка сработает при изменении ссылки на "string[] ListResult", а не ListResult[1] или сортировки содержимого.

Как вариант, можно использовать индексатор (стоит учесть это при реализации сортировки в методе lg.sorted()):

```
public string this[int index]
{
  get
  {
     return ListResult[index];
  }
  set
  {
     ListResult[index] = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("ListResult");
   }
}
```

Comment: Я понял. Огромное спасибо!